# MySQL query not using index correctly?

Tags: mysql, sql, query-optimization

I have 2 tables - `profile` with 1,500,000 records and `indicator_trades` with 12,000,000 records. The following query, which returns 0 results, takes about 10 seconds to complete.

```
SELECT `trd`.`symbol`, `p`.`type`
FROM `indicator_trades` AS `trd`
INNER JOIN `profile` AS `p` ON `p`.`symbol` = `trd`.`symbol`
WHERE `start_date` >= '2014-09-17' AND `p`.`type` = 2
```

DESCRIBE results:

```
+----+-------------+-------+--------+-----------------------+------------+---------+--------------------------+------+-------------+
| id | select_type | table | type   | possible_keys         | key        | key_len | ref                      | rows | Extra       |
+----+-------------+-------+--------+-----------------------+------------+---------+--------------------------+------+-------------+
|  1 | SIMPLE      | trd   | range  | IDX_symbol,start_date | start_date | 4       | NULL                     | 3662 | Using where |
|  1 | SIMPLE      | p     | eq_ref | IDX_symbol,type       | IDX_symbol | 34      | barchart_data.trd.symbol |    1 | Using where |
+----+-------------+-------+--------+-----------------------+------------+---------+--------------------------+------+-------------+
```

10 seconds seems like an abnormally long time for this query when it's using keys, but does it just take that long to pare down 3662 records from the 12,000,000 in the `indicator_trades` table?

SHOW CREATE on the two tables:

```
CREATE TABLE `indicator_trades` (
  `id` bigint(20) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `symbol` varchar(32) NOT NULL,
  `indicator_code` varchar(10) NOT NULL,
  `start_date` date DEFAULT NULL,
  `last_update` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  KEY `IDX_symbol` (`symbol`) USING BTREE,
  KEY `start_date` (`start_date`),
  KEY `indicator_code` (`indicator_code`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=12582721 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 ROW_FORMAT=COMPACT |

CREATE TABLE `profile` (
  `id` bigint(20) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `symbol` varchar(32) NOT NULL,
  `type` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `lastupdate` datetime NOT NULL DEFAULT '0000-00-00 00:00:00',
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  UNIQUE KEY `IDX_symbol` (`symbol`) USING BTREE,
  KEY `type` (`type`),
  KEY `exchange` (`exchange`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=320948248 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1
```

Comment: It needs to join 12 million rows. I think it is the inner join which makes it slow.

Comment: @S.Pols Shouldn't it only need to join 3662 records since the optimizer should reduce the data set with the WHERE before joining?

Comment: This sounds like `innodb_buffer_pool_size` variable is extremely low and you're hitting the disk instead of RAM. What does `SHOW VARIABLES LIKE '%buffer_pool%';` show?

Comment: @N.B. It shows a value of 4294967296.

Comment: That's ~4GB and it's *most likely* not sufficient to store all ~13.5m rows that you need to work with, which forces MySQL to use your HDD. Since your drive is mechanical (judging by the 10 second performance figute), that will make the whole operation slow. Solutions (at first hand) - increase buffer pool if you have sufficient RAM, get a better hard drive (SSD does the trick). Other solutions are to reduce the disk space spent - replace varchar `symbol` with an int fk if possible, try a different storage engine (TokuDB), remove indexes with low cardinality.

Comment: Have you tried forcing the index on the join? `FROM indicator_trades AS ted FORCE INDEX (IDX_symbol) INNER JOIN profile AS p FORCE INDEX (IDX_symbol)`

Comment: What would happen if you had a compound index instead (symbol,type)/(symbol,start_date)?

Answer (score 0):

At a first look your query should be fast, also described by the EXPLAIN output.

You cannot avoid disk reads because you need to get a field which is not in the index that is used (eg: using index `start_date`, but need to reed `symbol` field; using `symbol` index but reading `type` field).

Also you need to be sure all the indexes are loaded in memory (the buffer_pool setting allows you  to increase it).

Your query can be rewritten like this (i think the same performance should be expected):

```
SELECT `p`.`symbol`, 
       2 AS `type` 
FROM   `profile` AS `p` 
WHERE  `p`.`symbol` IN (SELECT DISTINCT( `trd`.`symbol` ) 
                        FROM   `indicator_trades` AS `trd` 
                        WHERE  `trd`.`start_date` >= '2014-09-17') 
       AND `p`.`type` = 2
```

But you can run the sub-query and let us know what is the speed for it:

```
SELECT DISTINCT( `trd`.`symbol` ) 
                            FROM   `indicator_trades` AS `trd` 
                            WHERE  `trd`.`start_date` >= '2014-09-17'
```